# Spark filter which order of operation O(1) or O(n)

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I'am trying to understand the concept of spark but just got confused at some point, wanted to know if spark.filter is O(n) or O(1) and what if I first sort the data and then put filtration, whether it will have any effect on order complexity.

So, will try to explain in more detail :-

```
Data (1,1,2,3,4,2,3)
Case 1 : Spark.filter(id.equals(3))
Case 2 : Spark.sortBy(id).filter(id.equals(3))
```

Which case will have which complexity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Spark SQL` has **Catalyst Query Optimizer** which takes care of how to execute the query.

**Catalyst** is the Spark SQL query optimizer, which is used to take the query plan and transform it into an execution plan that Spark can run.

Spark SQL builds up a tree representing our query plan, called a `logical plan`. 
Spark is able to apply a number of optimizations on the logical plan and can also choose between multiple physical plans for the same logical plan using a `cost-based model`.

For filters, **PushDownPredicate**  is used which is a part of Catalyst Optimizer.

When you execute `where or filter` operators right after loading a dataset, Spark SQL will try to push the where/filter predicate down to the data source using a corresponding SQL query with WHERE clause.

This optimization is called `filter pushdown or predicate pushdown` and aims at pushing down the filtering to the "bare metal", i.e. a data source engine.

> Filtering is performed at the very low level rather than dealing with
>   the entire dataset

for more information you can check these links:

[Catalyst Optimizer](https://databricks.com/blog/2015/04/13/deep-dive-into-spark-sqls-catalyst-optimizer.html)

[Predicate Pushdown](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/spark-sql-Optimizer-PushDownPredicate.html)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I have accepted your answer.